# how to use handlebars within an html input field?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have the following code:
    {{data.title}}

How can I get handlebars to render the information in the input field onto my html form?

```
<input class='add-title' name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a

```
value={{data.title}}
```

tag in the field and stringify it so it looks like this:

```
"{{data.title}}"
```

Comment: what's going on here?